# Puzzle : Find minimum resource allocation on multiple of 10 or 12 only

Tags: algorithm, math

I have two types of notebook where ,

- 10 problems could be solved in one page, in the first notebook.
- 12 problems could be solved in one page, in the second notebook.

For given n problems I have to use pages in such a way that no space from both notebook should be wasted ever .Taking consideration that I have to use minimum pages also .

Output should return number of pages need for solving all problem , if not passible it should return -1.

**Example :**

```
Problem count :  10

Output : 1 (one page from first notebook)

Problem Count :12

Output :1 (one page from second notebook)

Problem Count : 5

Output : -1 (Not possible)

Problem Count : 22

Output : 2(one from first notebook + one from second notebook)

Problem Count: 23

Output:-1(not possible)
```

How to approach this problem , thanks in advance

Comment: Why not boil it down to 5/6 (i.e. halve them). One is for the odd bit the other for the even.

Comment: How it is diffrent for odd bit and even bit ? @EdHeal

Comment: You need to try to solve this yourself.  After you try, then show us what you tried.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming, it's about basic number theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that the number of problems is 2k. It must be even for any combination of pages.

Then you have to find x and y such that

```
10x + 12y = 2k
5x + 6y = k
5(x + y) + y = k
```

You have to minimize x + y. Let a = x + y then,

```
5a + y = k
a >= y
```

One solution to this problem is

```
a' = floor(k / 5)
y' = k mod 5
```

This solution minimizes y, therefore for any aolution to exist, a' >= y' for this particular solution

A general solution to this equaltion would be

```
a = a' - t
y = y' + 5t
```

In the sense that y' borrows t from a'
Maximizing t would minimize a.

To solve:

```
a >= y
a' - t >= y' + 5t
a' - y' >= 6t
```

So max t is floor((a' - y')/6)
And min a is a' - t

Constant time solution! :)